# Tkinter not working as expected in Python 3

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this snippet of code and I expect it to create a gui with a bunch of buttons and a text box. But I only see the empty box with the title:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("title")

root.mainloop()

button1 = Button(root, text="button1")
button2 = Button(root, text="button2")
button3 = Button(root, text="button3")

text = Entry(root)
listbox = Listbox(root)

text.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
listbox.pack()
```

Is it because of inconsistencies between different versions of Python? I am trying to learn about Tkinter using this [quick guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-quickstart-to-building-gui-based-applications-in-python/)

Comment: `root.mainloop()` is being called before you declare the buttons. Move it to the end of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the call to `root.mainloop()` to the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do `root.mainloop()` at the end to get the code.

Comment: This was answered over a year ago. Duplicate answers are, at least, frowned upon